# Style host component based on model property

Tags: javascript, angular

I know about the different class approaches that you can take and the :host selector, however I want to apply conditional hosting based on a property that I have in my component class.

Let say I have

```
@Input('val') val: string;
```

Then based on that input I calculate the height of the element and want to apply it via the `host` configuration of the `@Component`. How do I do that?

I know a workaround using `ElementRef` and apply the styling with regular JavaScript, but I am not really happy with that approach, so I am looking for "the angular approach".

I am really struggling here with the lack of documentation on the Angular site and the total absence of real world examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can write something like this

```
  @Input('val') val: string;
  @HostBinding('style.height') get height {
    return this.val + 'px';
  }
```

See an example here https://plnkr.co/edit/kNSjCFG710xsCUiiBxat?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `@HostBinding` decorator like this:

```
@Input('val') val: string;
@HostBinding('attr.width')
width:string;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.width = this.val + 'px'; // for example
}
```

Comment: what about style="width: 300px" for example

for example

`@HostBinding('attr.style') componentWidth: string;`


and then 

`ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.componentWidth = "width: " + this.width + 'px';
  }`

Comment: It's rather: `@HostBinding('style.width') componentWidth: string;` and `ngAfterContentInit() { this.componentWidth = this.width + 'px'; }`